# IS $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\beta\cdot g(x)}g(x)^{\alpha-1}\text{d}x={\Gamma(\alpha)\over \beta^\alpha}\ \ ?$

Tags: probability, gamma-distribution, integral, transform, jacobian

Is the following statement true:

> Let $g(x)$ be some non negative continuous function of $x$.We know that$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\beta x}x^{\alpha-1}dx={\Gamma(\alpha)\over \beta^\alpha}$$
>
> Does the following hold as well: $$\int_{0}^\infty e^{-\beta\cdot g(x)}g(x)^{\alpha-1}dx={\Gamma(\alpha)\over \beta^\alpha}\ \ ?$$

Comment: The general statement is certainly false (consider $g\equiv 0$). Look at [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) - assuming a piecewise differentiable $g$, you will need its derivative $g'(x)$. Dividing the integral into two pieces, $\int_{-\infty}^0$ and $\int_0^\infty$, it looks to me like the specific statement for $g(x)=|x|$ is also false.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been wrongly posted: the claim made is trivial.

Comment: @Xi'an Since it is answered with upvotes, I can't

Comment: If you want a reasonably general result along those lines, to replace $x$ by $g(x)$ you need to replace $dx$ by $g'(x)\, dx$ (i.e. you need to keep the Jacobian of the transformation) --- and you need to also convert the limits on the integral when you transform. Then the substitution $u=g(x), du=g'(x) dx$ converts it back to an integral of the original form and you have a result similar to the one you describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, the relation is not true: consider $g(x) = 1$, in which case the integral is infinite.

Using the general framework of [integration by substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable), the following conditions are sufficient:

- $g$ is differentiable, with an integrable derivative
- $g(0) = 0$ and $g(\infty) = \infty$
- $g'(x) = 1$ for all $x$

This, unfortunately, only allows for the function $g(x) = x$.

Of course, this doesn't prove that the relation doesn't still hold for other $g$. But the most obvious way to show it doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my question. Please edit your answer so as to suit my new needs

Comment: Nonnegative is still not enough; consider $g(x) = 1$.

Comment: So, will it be possible to list down the exact conditions on $g$ such that this holds?